# How to add a city to a shapefile

Tags: r, spatial, r-sp

this might be a newish question. I have shapefile with Local Authorities, but one city is not in the file. I have another shapefile which has the city that is missing in my first file, but this is an older map of the country, so it doesn't include all the Local authorities.

My question is: Is there a way of using the information of the old map about this specific city to modify the file I'm using? if yes, could you please give some hints?

The city I'm interested in is called "Calera" in the old shapefile

The data is available on google drive
The shapefile I'm using is:

```
   chileusing <- readShapeSpatial('cl_comunas_geo', proj4string =CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"))
```

The old shapefile is:

```
    chileold<-readRDS("CHL_adm3.rds")
```

[data](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B1fBTI2yri4QWjRzME5lNElrdGs&usp=sharing)

Many thanks

Comment: this resource might help: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/maptools/vignettes/combine_maptools.pdf

Comment: Thanks! I'll check that and let you know